# Protobuf-net Extension interfaces

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have a problem understanding protobuf-net extensions and how they exactly work. I need to serialize a 2D custom class array and so I decited to wrap it into a class something like:

```
class CustomData : IExtension
{
     private CustomClass[,] data;
     public CustomClass this[int index_X, int index_Y]
      {
                get 
                {
                    return data[index_X, index_Y];
                }
                set
                {
                    data[index_X, index_Y] = value;
                }
            }

        public Stream BeginQuery()
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();

            int pos = 0;
            byte[] packedData = SomeStaticClass.ConvertToByteArray(data)

            using(var writer = new ProtoWriter(stream, null, null))
            {
                ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(1, WireType.String, writer);
                ProtoWriter.WriteBytes(packedData, writer);
            } 

            return stream;
        }

        public void EndQuery(Stream stream)
        {
            stream.Close();
        }

     //... and the other 3 implemented funcs from IExtension
}
```

So this ofcourse is in a custom IExtensible which has GetExtensionObject() returning an instance of the CustomData object. The problem comes when I try to append extension data to an instance. Here is what I'm doing:

```
public void DoAppend()
{
        var stream = new MemoryStream();

        using (ProtoWriter writer = new ProtoWriter(stream, null, null))
        {
            var test = new CustomExtensibleClass(300, 300);

            ProtoWriter.AppendExtensionData(test, writer);
        }

        var result = stream.ToArray();
}
```

The problem is that "result" contains no data. I expected that the data I appended and written via BeginQuery() will be transfered to the stream of the ProtoWriter but I suppose this is not the case.

Can somebody explaing what I am doing wrong or at least how can use the appended data?

Comment: Is this v1 or v2? It should work in v1... In v2 the extension piece is one of the very few remaining incomplete (along with GetProto). In progress...

Comment: This is v2 and I suppose that expains it. I will try a different approach. Thanks for the help.

Comment: it is very much on the short-term roadmap; problem is: I have finite time in each day